# Exactly $\phi(\phi(n))$ primitive roots modulo $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n\in \Bbb N$ is a primitive root then how to prove that:

There are exactly $\phi(\phi(n))$ primitive roots modulo $n$ such that are peer to peer $\not \equiv$

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/166866/264