# Exactly $\frac{p-1}{2} - \phi(p-1)$ incongruent quadratic nonresidues mod p that are not primitive roots mod p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are exactly $$\frac{p-1}{2} - \phi(p-1)$$ incongruent quadratic nonresidues modulo $p$ that are not primitive roots modulo $p$.

I have been looking at this problem for quite some time, but have not been able to make any headway. Can you assist?

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of subtracting the number of primitive roots mod $p$ from the number of quadratic nonresidues?

Comment: I see that now, guess my head was quite foggy last night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

First of all, if $a$ is a Quadratic Residue $\pmod p,$ there exists $x$ such that $x^2\equiv a\pmod p\implies a^{\frac{p-1}2}=x^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$

$\implies$ ord $_pa|\frac{p-1}2\implies a$ can not be a primitive roots i.e., primitive root must be  quadratic nonresidue.

Now use [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_Quadratic_Residues_of_a_Prime)  and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166866/prove-if-n-has-a-primitive-root-then-it-has-exactly-phi-phin-of-them)

Comment: Thank you! It's important to establish that primitive roots must be quadratic nonresidues. Thanks again.

Comment: @BoSchmidt, I realized that when I was supplying the links:). My pleasure