# What can we say about the number of generators in group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ ($p$ prime)?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$\mathbb{Z}^*_m = \{a \in \mathbb{Z}_m | \gcd(a, m) = 1\}$. As $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ is cyclic when $p$ is prime the group contains at least 1 generator. Can we say anything else about the number of generators in such a group?

Comment: Number of generators given by Euler $\phi$ function.

Comment: But doesn't the Euler function return the cardinality of the group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$?

Comment: Yes it does. I also gives number of integers relatively prime to $n$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155137/cyclic-group-generators-of-order-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Where is my mistake in this example: $\phi(19) = 18$ and the generators of $\mathbb{Z}^*_{19}$ are 2, 3, 10, 13, 14 and 15.

Comment: The multiplicative group has 18 elements and $\phi(18)=6$